# Cannot remove a column from Array python using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given the following array:

```
import numpy as np
G = np.array([[2.7, 0, -0.2, 0, -0.5, -1],
                  [0, 9, 0, 0, -10, 1],
                  [-0.2, 0, 4.2, -4, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, -4, 4, 0, 0],
                  [-1.5, -10, 0, 10.5, 0],
                  [-3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

If i remove a row from the array using `G = np.delete(G, 3, axis=0)`, it removes row at position 3 properly.

**But i cannot remove a column like this:** `G = np.delete(G, 3, axis=1)`

I get following error:

```
numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1.
```

Can someone please point me to the right way? what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Your array is broken. The row lengths don't match; `[-0.5, -10, 0, 10.5, 0]` only has 5 elements.

Comment: Did you look at `G` after creating it?  Does it look like a normal 2d numeric array?

Comment: @user2357112 you are right thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your array has shape of `(6,)` because your array lengths don't match. Check the second to last array. If you only have 5 observations, add `np.nan` to the end of row 5 (like this `[-1.5, -10, 0, 10.5, 0,np.nan]`,and you'll fix the problem.